# Rewiring KVM Buttons

Tags: soldering, button

Background: I'm working on a project that would allow a number of people to hook up their laptops to a single monitor through a KVM and use buttons on the desk to control who has control of the monitor. Originally, the plan was to use buttons with microcontrollers to send keyboard shortcuts to the KVM which would then switch to a given input based on what keyboard shortcut was sent. I've run into a problem because the keyboard switching is a little.. off. The only way to do it without installing software is to cycle through the inputs 1 by 1, and it's a requirement that the user not need to install anything. So now I'm wondering if its feasible to interact directly with the KVM hardware. Worst case scenario, we could just plant the KVMs on the table, but that's not quite as user-friendly.

Problem: I want to have a bunch of buttons on a table, ~6ft away from the KVM, which would replace the buttons on the KVM board. I'm not sure how to do this, but I have a few ideas (not sure if they're feasable):

1. Remove the buttons and solder wires in their place, which would be connect to the buttons on the table.
2. Connect the wires from the table buttons directly to the leads of the buttons on the board, without removing them.
3. Some kind of tiny motor or something that could push the buttons on the KVM. (Rather avoid this)

So I guess the question is: which of these would be the easiest, and what's the best way to go about it? Also open to suggestions on entirely different solutions..

First picture is of the top of the KVM, where the buttons are soldered onto the board, the second is the underside of the board. The button connections can be seen sticking out of the board.
[image: Top of KVM board]
[image: Bottom of KVM board]

Comment: A Kernel-based Virtual Machine with wires? Because that's what KVM means until you specify otherwise.

Comment: :s/KVM/KVM switch/g

Comment: Is this supposed to be more clear? Instead of once KVM you write it twice. Is it so hard to say what it stands for? And don't ":s" and "/g" me.

Comment: [KVM switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kvm_switch). Or just [Google KVM](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS488US488&sugexp=chrome,mod=2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=define%3Akvm)

Comment: @stevenvh, I think you'd be hard pressed to find someone who uses a KVM regularly call it a "Keyboard-Video-Mouse." A bit over the top, don't you think?

Comment: Nowhere in your question you mention "KVM switch", you just talk about KVM. Don't expect everybody to know what you're talking about, we just happen to bump into a question, with zero context. BTW, if you google it your first two hits are about the Virtual Machine. Also, your well-mannered comment has been flagged.

Comment: @Shamtam - Well, I don't use it regularly, actually never have. OP just obstinately refuses to say what it is, yet wants *me* to help him? Forget it.

Comment: @Mannimarco - If you want *me* to google KVM, why don't *you* google for an answer to your question?

Comment: @Mannimarco, to you KVM is obvious, to me wiring in buttons is obvious, do you see how different backgrounds mean different things? I only know KVM because an IT guy taught it to me a few weeks ago. He was asking for clarification and showing what he found looking it up. You are the one asking for help.

Comment: @Shamtam if you are discussing something we normally do not discuss here why not ask them for details.

Comment: I have no idea what ":s/KVM/KVM switch/g" means (if it means anything). stevenvh asked you a perfectly reasonable question, which you could have answered properly. Since your communication skills don't seem to be very good let me help you: you could have said "KVM stands for Keyboard-Video-Mouse". There, was that so hard?

Comment: For those curious, :s/KVM/KVM switch/g is a Vi command that replaces every instance of "KVM" with "KVM switch". I figured even stevenvh would know what a KVM switch was, and would grasp the meaning of the comment. Apparently I was wrong. For the rest of you, please don't let me interrupt your circle-jerk.

Comment: No, I didn't know what a KVM switch was, otherwise I wouldn't have asked. Like I said before, don't assume that others are busy with the same things you are. We get questions about all kinds of things, we don't know everything. So it would have helped if you wrote "Keyboard-Video-Mouse" in parenthesis after your first mention of KVM, even in the title. You also seem to assume that I use Vi. I don't, and so will a lot of others. Don't make assumptions. Lastly, you wrote the Vi command in a comment, but didn't apply it to the question. It still nowhere says "KVM switch".

Comment: C'mon guys, this is being overly pedantic, IMHO. The OP guy just wants to know if he can extend some buttons, it doesn't even matter what the device is. :|

Comment: @dextorb - Me no agree! English teacher say very important express yourself properly! Also, it *may* not matter what device it is, but you can't judge that if you don't *know* what it is. I actually stopped reading at the first "KVM" because I wanted to know what it was before I went on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply solder long wires to the back of the board where the buttons connect and put buttons on the ends of the wires.  If you get phantom switching (button presses when you weren't pressing a button) or several switches when you only press the button once then you'll have to look more carefully at the design of the circuit to eliminate false presses and properly debounce it.

But try long wires and buttons first - it should work fine.

The buttons you show have 4 pins. Connect your 2 wires to two diagonally opposite pins.

Comment: If using wires does not work a fall-back would be to use relays, placed near the buttons, switched by buttons via long wires. But thyat is probably not needed.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Thanks for the edit, very good method to ensure you have the two contacts for this switch type!  It seems like many of the movers and shakers on the piclist are here - glad to see you're here!

Comment: Played around with it a bit, the pairs are on the left and right. Works great when I'm just messing with it with a couple spare pieces of wire, but will using longer wires (6-10 feet) cause any problems? Not really a hardware guy, so I don't know how much the current or voltage would degrade over that range (if at all).

Comment: @Mannimarco It is very likely that those lead to high impedance inputs to the microcontroller that runs the KVM.  Very little current will be running on the wires.  The voltage drop will be very, very small due to the high impedance of the inputs, but even if the voltage drop is significant it will probably still work due to input level tolerances, which could allow a volt or more drop before having problems sensing the switch. Try it with long wires, then come back and describe any problems you encounter - chances are good that it'll simply work.

Comment: Awesome, not sure what impedance is but I can just Google that. Thank you for the assistance, kind sir.

Comment: @Mannimarco Don't worry about it.  In this case high impedance merely means that the input only needs a tiny current to activate at the required voltage level.  Good luck, let us know how it goes!